# Trouble running robot_upstart

Tags: ros, bashrc, ros-indigo, robot-upstart

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all.

I installed ros_upstart with this command `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-robot-upstar`.

I can find the files in `/opt/ros/indigo/lib/robot_upstart/` and `/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/robot_upstart`.

I also did `echo "source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc` and `source ~/.bashrc`.

After starting roscore I run this comand

```
rosrun robot_upstart install myrobot_bringup/launch/base.launch
```

and I get this error

```
Unable to locate path launch/base.launch in package myrobot_bringup. Installation aborted.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/robot_upstart/install", line 32, in <module>
    exit(main())
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/robot_upstart/install_script.py", line 83, in main
    if os.path.isfile(found_path[0]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I also tried `sudo service myrobot start` and got

```
myrobot: unrecognized service
```

Am I running the command in the wrong directory? Do I need to change something that is specific to my machine?

In advance. Thanks for any help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218146/trouble-running-robot_upstart/) by [MiniMe](https://answers.ros.org/users/22450/minime/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-09-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I had the same problems and errors at my Ubuntu armhf RPI2.

I've noticed that the armhf packages are too old and tried to compile from source.
Same problem!

**Plan-B:**

$sudo apt-get install daemontools

create a file /etc/init/svscan.conf

```
start on runlevel [2345]

expect fork
respawn
exec svscanboot
```

$sudo mkdir -p /etc/service/mockbot

create a file /etc/service/mockbot/run

```
#!/bin/bash
export USER=ros
export HOME=/home/$USER
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
exec /opt/ros/indigo/bin/roslaunch mockbot mockbot.launch
```

Check service

$sudo service svscan status

svscan start/running, process 835

$sudo svstat /etc/service/mockbot

/etc/service/mockbot: up (pid 849) 1443043529 seconds

Now, your ros launchfile will be startet at system boot.

Not perfect as robot_upstart, but it works ;-)

Cheers
Chrimo

---

Originally posted by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) with karma: 476 on 2015-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MiniMe](https://answers.ros.org/users/22450/minime/) on 2015-09-28**:
Thanks for the workaround but at the moment I'd like to continue with getting this going. If all else fails I'll try this.